# Chrome Browser tab crashes when not active

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

I have a heavy javascript code , something like below

```
for(i=1;i<=100;i++)
{
    var ceiv = 100.0* implied_volatility(0, ceprice,hmmprice, price, rfi, dvd, t)

}
    function implied_volatility(i, p, s, x, rfi, dvd, t) {
        var cv = function(sigma) {
            var sst = sigma * Math.sqrt(t);
            var d1 = (Math.log(s / x) + (rfi - dvd + sigma * sigma / 2.0) * t) / sst;
            var d2 = d1 - sst;
            var Nd1 = cdf_stdgauss(d1);
            var Nd2 = cdf_stdgauss(d2);



            if (i == 7) {
                Nd1 = Nd1 - 1.0;
                Nd2 = Nd2 - 1.0;
            }
            return s * Math.exp(-dvd * t) * Nd1 - x * Math.exp(-rfi * t) * Nd2 - p;
        };
        var cvp = function(sigma) {
            var sst = sigma * Math.sqrt(t);
            var d1 = (Math.log(s / x) + (rfi - dvd + sigma * sigma / 2.0) * t) / sst;
            return s * Math.exp(-dvd * t) * pdf_stdgauss(d1) * Math.sqrt(t);
        };
        return newt_root(0.2, cv, cvp, 0.000001);
    }
```

when I reopen the  minized or not active tab its getting crashed , but when tab is in focus it runs smooth.How do I avoid it ?

Comment: What does "crashed" mean?

Comment: hand , non responsive